# oculus quest 2 screen record using adb shell command

Tags: android, adb, oculusquest

I'm trying to record the oculus quest 2's screen using adb commands `adb shell screenrecord`.

I expected a recorded video shows a wide screen video. However, the recorded video shows 2 square screens.

Actually in the other VR device, pico Neo 2, the recorded video shows a wide screen video.

So, I wonder why the command `adb shell screenrecord` makes oculus quest 2 make a video that has two square screen.

And, the below image is the caputred image of the video recorded in oculus quest 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkROC.jpg)

Comment: This is how a typical 3d helmet screen should look like. It is a widescreen video, with 2 areas meant for 2 eyes. Try showing what you want.

Comment: I want to get screen that one eye sees

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SCRCPY](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to record the video from the Quest 2. This also works for applications using passtrough. Put in the following command to go from two square screens to one.

```
scrcpy --crop 1730:974:1934:450 --max-fps 30
```

Then use

```
scrcpy --record file.mp4
```

to record video